# How to add legend to seaborn multi-dist plot without putting the data together

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a two series of data that i'm displaying on one seaborn histogram using the following code:

```
import pandas
import seaborn 

d10_ft = check3[(check3['choice'] == 1)&(check3['decile'] == 10)]['TOTL_SQ_FT_CNT']
d1_ft = check3[(check3['choice'] == 1)&(check3['decile'] == 1)]['TOTL_SQ_FT_CNT']

sns.distplot(d10_ft, label = 'decile 10')
sns.distplot(d1_ft, label = 'decile 1')
```

The graph itself displays exactly want but the label will not show up differentiating the color.  How do I get the label to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to create something that looks like your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

check3 = pd.DataFrame({'choice':np.random.randint(0,2,5000),
                       'decile':np.random.randint(0,11,5000),
                      'TOTL_SQ_FT_CNT':np.random.normal(0,1,5000)})
```

Using your code, but assigning the plots to an axes:

```
d10_ft = check3[(check3['choice'] == 1)&(check3['decile'] == 10)]['TOTL_SQ_FT_CNT']
d1_ft = check3[(check3['choice'] == 1)&(check3['decile'] == 1)]['TOTL_SQ_FT_CNT']

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
sns.distplot(d10_ft, label = 'decile 10',ax=ax)
sns.distplot(d1_ft, label = 'decile 1',ax=ax)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

If you use the latest version of seaborn 0.11.1 [see help page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), i think you can directly provide the colour as hue.